# Adding Two Numbers Entered as Strings in Textfields

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have two text fields in which numbers are inputed as strings. I need to convert the strings to numbers, add them together and then display the result in a 3rd textfield.

I am totally new to iPhone programming .. So please don't be hard on me :P

Ok here is the problem

AdditionViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AdditionViewController : UIViewController 
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *Number1;
    IBOutlet UITextField *Number2;
    IBOutlet UITextField *SumAnswer;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) UITextField *Number1;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UITextField *Number2;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UITextField *SumAnswer;
-(IBAction)buttonPressed1:(id)sender;

@end
```

AdditionViewController.m

```
#import "AdditionViewController.h"

    @implementation AdditionViewController
    @synthesize Number1;
    @synthesize Number2;
    @synthesize SumAnswer;


    -(IBAction)buttonPressed1:(id)sender
    {
        SumAnswer.text = Number1.text + Number2.text; 
           // I want the above line to be edited so that I can get the addition
             of both the numbers in the 3rd Text Field 
    }

    -
    -
    -
    -
    -
    @end
```

I am really new to iPhone programming .. I am trying to understand how NSString can be used here .. But I am finding it a bit complicated .

If someone please tell me what the code should be ... It will be a great help . I have to submit a mini project to my school asap .

Thanking You , int3rc3pt0r

Comment: One small not-entirely-relevant point: naming convention for Objective-C is class names start with capital letters, class member names do not. So you would have `number1` instead of `Number1`.

Comment: Make sure to hit the checkmark next to the best answer so that the system knows the question as been answered and the person who helped you gets the credit and rep points.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

NSString has method allowing to get numeric value from it (e.g. `intValue`, `floatValue` etc) - you can use them to convert string to numbers. To convert numbers to string you can use `stringWithFormat:` method - the way it takes [format specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/formatSpecifiers.html) is similar to `printf` function in c.

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed1:(id)sender
{
    // You may also need to check if your string data is a valid number
    int result = [Number1.text intValue] + [Number2.text intValue];
    SumAnswer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", result];
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it.. also check that the boxes and button are linked in interface builder

Comment: Do you need `try/catch` to check if the text can be parsed into `int`?

Answer (score 4):

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed1:(id)sender
    {
        double answer = [Number1.text doubleValue] + [Number2.text doubleValue]; 
        SumAnswer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", answer];
    }
```

Comment: @ kubi ... when i enter 1.2 in number1 and 0.2 in number2 
i get answer as 1.0000 whats going wrong ?

Comment: sorry my bad ..i was taking as intValue instead of doubleValue ..
thankx a ton anyway ... thankx again

Comment: because it is formatted as a double number :D you need to declare a NSNumberFormatter if you want to format it in your style. "1.0000" is infact 1, but it is formatted as a double number